# The definition of density

Tags: terminology, density

Could density be defined as the measure of *matter* per unit volume instead of *mass* per unit volume because mass is a measurement of matter?

Answer (score 7):

It depends, there are different kinds of densities: mass density, particle density, charge density, probability density ...

Depending on how your measure your matter, mass, number of particles, charge (e.g. for electrons), you could use the corresponding density.

"Matter per unit volume" would only work in a broader sense, since it does not specifically state what kind of measure you want to use. Most of the time one simply defaults on mass, but this depends on the specific field.

Comment: I'd be more heavy handed. I don't see how matter per unit volume could ever work. "Matter" is ambiguous as you point out. Does "matter" mean mass, number of particles, charge, ect?

Comment: You could still state that you have more (or less) of something. And the different kinds of densities may correlate, e.g. more particles are usually more mass (unless you replace heavier particles by one lighter ones). But if you need to put numbers on it, then yes, you need to state what you are talking about.